# Transform Variable value in quoted string for connec string in dblink postgresl

Tags: postgresql, dblink

In `Postgresql 9.1`, the connect string of `dblink` must be in quoted string.

My issue is that my `dbname` come from a variable value

```
\set connect quote_ident('dbname=mydb')        
SELECT dblink_connect(connect);
```

`quote_ident` or `quote_literal` doesn't work. How put value is this quoted string ?

Comment: can show how variable holds your `dbname` ??

Answer (score 1):

you no need to use quote like that, just see this example

```
create or replace function fn_test_dblink (db text) returns text as 
$$
select dblink_connect('dbname='||db||' ')
$$
language sql
```

here am passing the *Database* name to  `db` in the `function` `fn_test_dblink`

```
select fn_test('GBL') -- GBL is my Database
```

you simply give variable to

`select dblink_connect('dbname='||your_variable||' ')`

instead of this
 `\set connect quote_ident('dbname=mydb')`

Comment: GBL came from a bash script with : psql .... - f .../this_script -v GBL=mydb. I tried your answer : create or replace function fn_string_dblink (db text) returns text as 
$$
select dblink_connect('dbname='||db||' ')
$$
language sql;
select fn_string_dblink(:GBL);    and I get column "mydb" does not exist